# Prepare Data Frames to be compared. Index manipulation, datetime and beyond

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Ok, this is a question in two steps.

**Step one:** I have a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
         date     time    value
0    20100201        0       12
1    20100201        6       22
2    20100201       12       45
3    20100201       18       13
4    20100202        0       54
5    20100202        6       12
6    20100202       12       18
7    20100202       18       17
8    20100203        6       12
...
```

As you can see, for instance between rows 7 and 8 there is data missing (in this case, the value for the 0 time). Sometimes, several hours or even a full day could be missing.

I would like to convert this DataFrame to the format like this:

```
                       value
2010-02-01 00:00:00       12
2010-02-01 06:00:00       22
2010-02-01 12:00:00       45
2010-02-01 18:00:00       13
2010-02-02 00:00:00       54
2010-02-02 06:00:00       12
2010-02-02 12:00:00       18
2010-02-02 18:00:00       17
...
```

I want this because I have another DataFrame (let's call it "reliable DataFrame") in this format that I am sure it has no missing values.

**EDIT 2016/07/28:** Studying the problem it seems there were also duplicated data in the dataframe. See the solution to also address this problem.

**Step two:** With the previous step done I want to compare row by row the index in the "reliable DataFrame" with the index in the DataFrame with missing values.

I want to add a row with the `value` NaN where there are missing entries in the first DataFrame. The final check would be to be sure that both DataFrames have the same dimension.

I know this is a long question, but I am stacked. I have tried to manage the dates with the `dateutil.parser.parse` and to use `set_index` as the method to set a new index, but I have lots of errors in the code. I am afraid this is clearly above my pandas level.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1 Answer**

```
df['DateTime'] = (df['date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['time'].astype(str) +':'+'00'+':'+'00').apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x)))

df.set_index('DateTime', drop=True, append=False, inplace=True, verify_integrity=False)

df.drop(['date', 'time'], axis=1, level=None, inplace=True, errors='raise')
```

**If there are duplicates these can be removed by:**

`df = df.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset='DateTime',keep='last').set_index('DateTime')`

**Step 2**

```
df_join = df.join(df1, how='outer', lsuffix='x',sort=True)
```

Comment: Step 2 is difficult without an example frame.  Although a `merge` or `join` will probably suffice.

Comment: Ok, I have added `df['time'].astype(str)` in `df['time']` to join int and str, but the last line of step 1 raise an error: `raise AssertionError('axis must be a MultiIndex')`

Comment: I've updated `level=None`, I'm using mostly `MultiIndex`

Comment: Step one seems to work, thank you. Now I have no time, I will try step 2 next.

Comment: Ok, in step 2 there are errors. `KeyError: DateTime` is what appears. I am assuming that `df1` is the full dataframe, where I have the complete set of values for each day and hour, and `df` is the dataframe we have given the correct format. Right? What I want is to include a row with a `NaN` value for each row in `df` that isn't present in `df1`.

Comment: you need to ensure the column headings match in both dataframes before merge or join`df.columns`, `df1.columns`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118522/discussion-between-david-and-toasteez).